# Linq to Entity skipping OrderBy with SelectMany

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm running into quite a strange behaviour using Linq to Entity (code first).

All my entities, context, databases are working fine, it's an ongoing project that is developed, updated and online for two years. I'm using .NET 4.5, EF 5. For that specific query, LazyLoading is disabled (not that activating it changes anything).

I have the following tables (I'm only mentionning what is related to the issue) :

- Games, which holds the games
- Press, which holds press articles about games
- PressTypes, which holds the categories for a press article
- Press_Games, which defines a one to many between Press to Games (one article can be about many games)

About the tables and their matching entity :

- Games has many fields, but let's say that it just holds two : ID (guid) and Name, the game's name.
- Press also has many fields, amongst which we have : ID (guid), CategoryID (guid) and UpdateDate (DateTime) that represents the last time the article has been updated.
- Press Entity has a Category Object, and an IEnumerable Games.
- Game Entity does NOT have a Press navigation property (intended and needed this way)
- PressTypes is the list of the press article categories, and has an ID (guid)
- Press_Games has two fields, GameID (guid) and PressID (guid)

I need to get the list of the 5 games that are linked to the latest press articles of a specific category. I retrieve them through the following query :

```
Context.Press
    .Where(press => press.Category.ID == MagicValues.ReviewGuid)) // MagicValues.ReviewGuid returns a Guid
    .OrderByDescending(press => press.UpdateDate)
    .SelectMany(press => press.Games)
    .Take(5);
```

The resulting list get a list of games, but not the one matching the expected chronological articles order. Using LINQPad I noticed that the generated query is the following :

```
SELECT TOP (5) 
[Join1].[ID] AS [ID], 
[Join1].[Name] AS [Name], 
FROM  [dbo].[Press] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent2].[PressID] AS [PressID], [Extent3].[ID] AS [ID] /* lots of selected fields */
    FROM  [dbo].[Press_Games] AS [Extent2]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Games] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent3].[ID] = [Extent2].[GameID] ) AS [Join1] ON [Extent1].[ID] = [Join1].[PressID]
WHERE cast('b5c18183-14e2-4bf2-b4e1-641b56694c55' as uniqueidentifier) = [Extent1].[CategoryID]
```

No ORDER BY. If I alter slightly the query to select the articles instead of the games, I get the proper list of articles, and their games, in the expected order :

```
Context.Press
    .Include(press => press.Games)
    .Where(press => press.Category.ID == MagicValues.ReviewGuid)) // MagicValues.ReviewGuid returns a Guid
    .OrderByDescending(press => press.UpdateDate)
    .Take(25);
```

The generated SQL query becomes :

```
SELECT 
[Project2].[C1] AS [C1], 
[Project2].[ID] AS [ID], 
[Project2].[Name] AS [Name], 
FROM ( 
    /* Lots of irrelevant stuff with JOINs and SELECTs */
)  AS [Project2]
ORDER BY [Project2].[UpdateDate] DESC, [Project2].[ID] ASC, [Project2].[C2] ASC
```

I get the ORDER BY back (which was more or less expected as it's working).

**So (finally) my question is: is this behavior expected or is it a bug ?**

I'm thinking that since I'm using SelectMany, EF seems to think that only the Games table is required and thus ignore the OrderBy on Press. It could make sense, but seems a bit counterintuitive.

I'll find a way to circumvent the issue (unless there is actually a clean fix for this) but I'm mostly curious about the behavior and the explanation.

Comment: Some old MSDN thread with similar issue - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7b8cabd2-f2f7-4413-b611-6234531c565f/linq-orderby-confusion?forum=adodotnetentityframework

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is about the inner machinery of EF, so I have to guess here. It looks like EF's smartness to build the most economic query possible causes it to err here.

### Query 1

Let's look at some simplified queries that demonstrate what happens.

First, the barebone form...

```
from p in Context.Press
from g in p.Games
select g
```

This is equivalent to `Context.Press.SelectMany(press => press.Games)`. By the way, note that there is a many to many association between `Press` and `Game`, because you've got this junction table `Press_Games`. You can assign the same `Game` to multiple `Press` objects (although you may not do that).

EF's query generation capabilities have often been denigrated, but at least it is smart enough to see that in this barebone query it only needs the tables `Games` and `Press_Games` to produce the output. `Press` is not in the SQL query.

If you add the predicate...

```
from p in Context.Press
from g in p.Games
where p.Category.ID == guid
select g
```

...you'll see that `Press` is joined in to satisfy the predicate. The SQL query only contains `Press` fields that are necessary for the join and the predicate. Another optimization is that `Press.CategoryID` is used in the SQL query, `Category` is not joined.

So EF puts a lot of effort in minimizing the number of accessed tables and fields in a SQL query. This effort seems to be **driven by the output**: no `Press` data returned, no `Press` data selected.

No let's add ordering to the barebone query (ignoring the descending part which is not essential here)...

```
from p in Context.Press
orderby p.UpdateDate
from g in p.Games
select g
```

This `orderby` clause has no effect whatsoever! You'll see that the generated SQL is the same with or without it.

I think that EF "reasons" that the output is about `Games` only –`from g in p.Games` is what's been asked for– so everything else in the query is about how to get the data, not how to shape the output.

But if you do...

```
from p in Context.Press
from g in p.Games
orderby p.UpdateDate
select g
```

...the ordering follows the requested output and it is applied. Again, I have to guess about EF's inner logic, but I think this is what's going on.

I use query syntax, because in fluent the latter LINQ statement translates to a `SelectMany` overload that is much more verbose. But **this query returns the data the way you are looking for.**

In my opinion the position of the `orderby` shouldn't matter (as you say, it's counterintuitive), but, well, it does.

### Query 2

Here, `Press` is the requested output, so it makes sense that any ordering is applied, irrespective of where it is positioned in the query. Note that selecting `Press` with `Games` included is quite different than what happens in query 1.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer. Your suggestion also works fine... until I throw a Distinct() into the mix : var games = from p in Press ... games.Distinct().Take(5); But on that issue, I think it's more a constraint from the SQL Server as it can't ORDER BY on a field that is not part of the SELECT DISTINCT. Yet, if I "force" EF to take a first batch on this and apply the Distinct() on this, I get the expected result : games.Take(100).Distinct().Take(5); The generated SQL query looks a lot to what I wrote as I was going to run a SqlQuery on the collection.

Comment: It's also logical: `Distinct` games can't be ordered by something in `Press`, because one `Game` in the output may have belonged to multiple `Press`es.